# UITable View Insert Row - can I press the actual cell rather than the green plus?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My table view is set up such that pressing "edit" creates an insert row using UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert. The cell reads "add new item" and has a green plus next to it.

When the user taps the green plus, a modal view controller pops up so they can add a new item. This is fine. But it only works if they press the green plus itself - not the "add new item" cell.

How can I make it so that pressing the cell itself will do the same as the green plus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can; you just have to handle the selection yourself. First set allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES, as shown above, then in the delegate's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, check to see if the selected row is the last row (or whatever row has your plus icon). If it is, run the same code you do in the `didCommitEditingStyle:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,Not possible because the entire edit mode process of `UITableView`  is controlled by iOS (done by private API's) not exposed to us. we do have delegated (UITableViewDelegate) functions but not sufficient to get your work done.

Although, we can show the selection on the table Cell while in edit mode.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsSelectionDuringEditing
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html